# What is my subnet and gateway

Tags: networking, lan, wan

When I connect my iPad to my Mac using personal hotspot, do I form a LAN? If yes, then what should be my subnet and what acts as my gateway?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I have got a right answer and I have given everything that can be possibly needed, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will form a LAN, a wireless LAN to be precise.

The device providing the "hotspot" (whether it's the Mac or the iPad) will be the gateway.

Your subnet and gateway information will be delivered to the connecting device via DHCP. I do not have Apple stuff, but I understood it will be in the 172.20.10.0/24 range, if everything is default.

Comment: I do get the feeling that though it's technically a LAN that is formed, each individual device connected gets its own 'pipe' & cannot see other devices without further configuration.

Comment: It may very well be, that this hotspot uses client-isolation or private VLANs with the gateway as promiscuous port.

Comment: It seems though that OP has the iPad actually hosting the hotspot; macOS doesn't use the name "personal hotspot".

Comment: @user1686 Yeah, the OP's usage of 'to' & 'from' feels backwards.

Comment: Ljm - I just checked - it does use 172.20.1.0 but /28 gateway at .1

Answer (score 1):

By connecting to the router, you will be joining all the other connected
devices. The router creates a LAN where the devices can access the router
and any other connected device.

To get the router and gateway IP address in iOS, do the following:

- Open the Settings app in iOS and go to the "Wi-Fi" section
- Locate the name of the Wi-Fi network that is currently connected,
  and tap on the "(i)" blue info button next to it
- Look under the IP Address section for "Router", the number next to this
  is the IP address for that router or gateway.

[image]